# why the value of variable doesn't show as expected?

Tags: javascript, lexical-scope

there is a high vote answer of lexical scope in StackOverflow(or some other q&a website, I'm not sure) describing as

```
function a() {

    var x
    x = 3
    function b() {
        x = 4
    }
    function c(){
        var x
        b()
    }

    c()
    print(x)
}
```

the answer in general is like

```
if(final output is 4):
    it is lexical scope
elif(final output is 3):
    it's dynamic scope
```

I make a conclusion:

1. so lexical scope has nothing to do with where to invoke the function, but where to define the function.

   if lexical scope relates to where to invoke the function:
       b() is invoked in c(), final output should be 3
2. normal variable all follows lexical scope rule

---

following is my code

```
let a = "before f()"

function f(){
    console.log(a) 
}

f() -->output: before f()

a = "before b() after f()"

f() -->output: before b() after f()
```

My Question:
why invoking f() the second time it's `before b() after f()`, not `before f()`?

this is the process I think

```
invoking f() the second time
go to function definition and try to find value of a
go to lexical scope where it's out and up to function definition 
find a = "before f()"
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the question you're referring to?

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth  I try to search in StackOverflow, but I can't find it. I'm not sure about where is it, because it was recorded in my note book  long time ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope determines *which* variable is used and depends on where the function is declared.

The *value* that is used will be the value of that variable *at the time* you read from it (which will be when the function is called).

Comment: Would there be any way such that `function c()` variable `var x` be affected and returned in print() statement that too without using `return` statement.Just by jumbling up the current code shifting var keyword here and there?

Comment: It is scoped to function c, so it can't be affected by code that is not inside function c.

Comment: If the body of function b is also nested inside function c the print statement would log undefined but the variable of function c would be getting the new value set by b nonetheless... right?